# How list only systemd service names, and loop over them?

Tags: linux, services, systemd, list, systemctl

I would like to loop over systemd service names, but can find no option to output just the service names, and have tried using cut, but without success.

```
._. systemctl list-units | cut -f 1 -d=
  UNIT LOAD   ACTIVE SUB       DESCRIPTION                                                          
 ...
  thermald.service   loaded active running   Thermal Daemon Service
 ...
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Did you try running `man systemctl` + `man cut` and reading the documentation available there? It seems `systemctl list-units --type service --plain --quiet | awk '{ print $1 }'` would do what you're requesting, would it not?

Comment: You tell me, sampi! You're the one with the answer. I'm merely the one with the question. Did I search the manpages, you say? Is that a rhetorical question? Of course I searched the manpages. I found no answers. So I came here. Is that okay? In any case, your answer solves the problem. So thank you. Please do post it as answer so I can give it recognition as such.

Comment: What you had tried wasn't entirely clear from the question. It's always okay to ask. I don't think I'm in enough need of recognition to transform the comment into an answer. Glad it helped!

Comment: The answer would not be for your sake, it makes it easier for other people to find the answer who share the same problem. The points are just meant to nudge you into doing the thing that helps the site function the way it was intended.

Comment: Anyway, just where do you think in the documentation does it say where to list just service names?

Comment: You could at least tag your question with the operating system. Please [edit] and do so.

Comment: So can you, David, if you see the edit is required! It would have taken you less time!

Comment: Since it was trivial, I posted a comment. Maybe it would had been more appropriate to have flagged as **needs improvement**? I have a very hard time seeing how the question, as currently phrased, can be of much help to others. I'm sure you've seen [how to ask](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) before. While your question makes sense, it is not of high enough quality for me personally to be prepared spending more time on it than I already have. Sorry.